# R/ RStudio - system path issue

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I think I did some damage to my system path and now I am unable to knit in RStudio. I have the most current version of R and RStudio.

Here is what i'm working with

```
Sys.getenv()
```

OUTPUT:

```
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING        0x20C97408:0x0:0x0
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render     /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.g6i2lhsTBr/Render
DISPLAY                        :0
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Users/lewa8222/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib::
EDITOR                         vi
GIT_ASKPASS                    rpostback-askpass
HOME                           /Users/lewa8222
LANG                           en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE                       en_US.UTF-8
LN_S                           ln -s
LOGNAME                        lewa8222
MAKE                           make
PAGER                          /usr/bin/less
PATH                           :/Users/lewa8222/anaconda/bin/python/:/Users/lewa8222/anaconda/bin/python/:/Users/lewa8222/anaconda/bin/python:/Users/lewa8222/anaconda/bin/python:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
R_BROWSER                      /usr/bin/open
R_BZIPCMD                      /usr/bin/bzip2
R_DOC_DIR                      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc
R_GZIPCMD                      /usr/bin/gzip
R_HOME                         /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
R_INCLUDE_DIR                  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
R_LIBS_SITE                    
R_LIBS_USER                    ~/Library/R/3.3/library
R_PAPERSIZE                    a4
R_PDFVIEWER                    /usr/bin/open
R_PLATFORM                     x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
R_PRINTCMD                     lpr
R_QPDF                         /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf
R_RD4PDF                       times,inconsolata,hyper
R_SESSION_TMPDIR               /var/folders/43/4q82487d5xsfpxdx6nl_c1wmhckx08/T//RtmpXOclp9
R_SHARE_DIR                    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share
R_SYSTEM_ABI                   osx,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?
R_TEXI2DVICMD                  /usr/local/bin/texi2dvi
R_UNZIPCMD                     /usr/bin/unzip
R_ZIPCMD                       /usr/bin/zip
RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH         /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-26
RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH              /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rpostback
RS_SHARED_SECRET               0255dad0-e77a-4d8c-bba9-0dc9e68fa0ff
RSTUDIO                        1
RSTUDIO_PANDOC                 /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc
RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT           23768
RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY          lewa8222
RSTUDIO_WINUTILS               bin/winutils
SED                            /usr/bin/sed
SHELL                          /bin/bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK                  /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.X0TdgERzV2/Listeners
TAR                            /usr/bin/tar
TMPDIR                         /var/folders/43/4q82487d5xsfpxdx6nl_c1wmhckx08/T/
USER                           lewa8222
XPC_FLAGS                      0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME               0
```

Notice the path

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

I was trying to link my anaconda version of python as the main python kernel in RStudio / RMarkdown.

To do this i used

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/Users/lewa8222/anaconda/bin/python/", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

Not knowing that each time I think it was appending to my Path.

Now, when i try to knit a file using the knit button in rstudio it fails as follows:

```
Error: 1:11: unexpected '/'
1: .libPaths(/
              ^
Execution halted
```

Any idea how I can fix this knitr error?

I have spent a lot of time on stack overflow and Rstudio help and can't seem to find a solution that works. 
Thank you
Leah

UPDATE! Thanks to the answer below from @carsonfarmer

I had to

1. find my .Rprofile file. this was located in my home user directory on my MAC.
2. then i opened it with atom (use whatever text editor you'd like but i did 
   atom .Rprofile in my user dir where the file was.

when i opened it i noticed the text in the file was this:

`.libPaths(/Users/lewa8222/anaconda/bin/python)`

the comment below from @kevinushey was on track - i just didn't understand what libPaths was to know i had a file with a call to it somewhere.

.libPaths - notice that the path doesn't have quotes around it. Every time i loaded R i was getting this error but i didn't notice it.

I changed the path to:

`.libPaths("/Users/lewa8222/anaconda/bin/python")`

and magic happened. the error went away. 
I hope this helps someone else and thank you everyone who helped me resolve this!!

Comment: That error is a plain R parse error -- do you have a `.libPaths()` call somewhere with an unexpected `/`?

Comment: @KevinUshey i don't have a libsPath() call - this happens when i try to knit a basic rmd document - the template file that rstudio creates

Comment: Do you get this error with `knit()` on the command line?

Comment: @Spacedman i don't - its only when using the knit BUTTON in r studio. really weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like @kevin-ushey was on the right track: Since knitr is basically running a new `R` instance each time you knit the document, it is loading your `.RProfile` each time (assuming you have one in your user dir), and I suspect your `.RProfile` has that offending `.libPaths(/` call in it. Try editing your `.RProfile` file... it looks like all you need to do it wrap whatever offending path is in there in quotes :)

Running the following from an `R` terminal should tell you where your user `.RProfile` is: `file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile")`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to link your anaconda to R/RStudio is to set the path to the `RETICULATE_PYTHON` variable

The best way is to create a .Renviron file and put it in:

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON="path to anaconda env that you need"
```